# Single- Valued Extension Property of a linear operator

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Please suggest books on Single- Valued Extension Property of a linear operator and on Spectral Projection of a linear operator.

Answer (score 0):

For the single-valued extension property of a linear operator, see the third volume of *Linear operators*, by Nelson Dunford and Jacob T. Schwartz.

Comment: In this book single valued extension property is given for spectral operators only. I need for any linear operator on Banach space. @Jose Carlos Santos